# Updating mobx store observable within self results in 'Cannot read property of <observable> of undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, mobx, mobx-react

I know that several similar issues like that exist already. However, having reviewed many of them I was not able to find solution to my problem. Here is the situation:

I want my `ReportStore` to fetch data from the server in form of an array and store them in an observable map. Fetching part is OK, the  data is coming correctly. The problem occurs when I try to write values to observable map inside of `requestNewReports` method. Here is the store code:

**ReportStore.ts**

```js
import api from "../api";
import { observable, action, ObservableMap } from "mobx";
import { IReportMetaData } from "../pages/ManagerView/TicketSales";
import { notificationStore } from "./NotificationStore";

export class ReportStore {
  fetchedReports: ObservableMap<number, IReportMetaData>;

  constructor() {
    this.fetchedReports = observable.map({});
  }

  async requestNewReports(fromDate: string = '', toDate: string = '') {
    try {
      const res = await api.get("reports/filtered", {
        params: {
          fromDate: from,
          toDate: to
        }
      });
      res.data.forEach((row: IReportMetaData, index: number) => {
        if (!this.fetchedReports.has(index)) {
          this.fetchedReports.set(index, row);
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      return notificationStore.showError(err.message);
    }
  }
}

export const reportStore = new ReportStore();
```

The store is being provided in `app.tsx` via `<Provider reportStore={reportStore}>....</Provider>` and injected in the components like that:

```js
export interface ITicketSalesProps {
  reportStore?: ReportStore;
}


export const TicketSales = inject('reportStore')(observer((props: ITicketSalesProps) => {
   // Component logic
}
```

And being called like that:

```js
// inside TicketSales
useEffect(() => {
  const { fetchedReports, requestNewReports } = props.reportStore!;
    if (fetchedReports.size === 0) {
      requestNewReports();
    }
  }, []);
```

**My setup:**
`create-react-app` via `npx` with `TypeScript`,

```
"mobx": "^5.15.3",
"mobx-react": "^6.1.4",
```

According to some issues the problem lies in legacy decorators. However,according to official `mobx` [documentation](https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html)

> Decorators are only supported out of the box when using TypeScript in create-react-app@^2.1.1. In older versions or when using vanilla JavaScript use either the decorate utility, eject, or the customize-cra package.

Which seems to be exactly my case.

Hence I am out of ideas of why it can be broken...
I even tried to eject and try babel plugin as was suggested in some issues:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose" : true }]
  ]
}
```

But no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this issue comes from your javascript code in general and not mobx.

From what I can read here, `requestNewReports()` is not a **bound method**. In your component you destructure your store and assign requestNewReports to a new variable so `"this"` is not your store anymore. Thus you have the "undefined" error.

You could change it to:

```
// inside TicketSales
useEffect(() => {
  const {reportStore} = props
  if (reportStore.fetchedReports.size === 0) {
    reportStore.requestNewReports();
  }
}, []);
```

Or, you could bind the method to the instance like:

```
...
  constructor() {
    this.fetchedReports = observable.map({});
    this.requestNewReports = this.requestNewReports.bind(this)
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. Had to bring myself back to shape after sever sickness. Yes exactly useEffect was the problem.

Comment: @watty Could you accept the answer, then? good that you feel better.